# MS Chart with Time x Axis like 00:00:00 and x value data in millisecond and increase data in run time

Tags: c#, mschart

I have some millions rows of data starting from 0 to 20,000,000 with step 10. This data are time series (in milliseconds) received from my device that is connected to my PC.

I want to plot this data as x value with their y values, and I want to have an x-axis label like 00:00:00. My data received is live and I want to have a live plot.

Please give me some code for config MS Chart to have this plot

Comment: You shouldn't ask questions requesting people to write the code for you.  You need to make an attempt at it or use an existing example and then get help solving any problems you run into. See https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: I just want to configure the MS-Chart so as to show the x-axis label values like 11:23:35.120 instead of milliSecond

Answer (score 0):

First I am going to assume your data is a DateTime or DateTimeOffset.  In order to specify a format for the DateTime values on the X-axis you would use something like this:

```cs
MyChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "hh:mm:ss.fff";
```

Also see [Custom date and time formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) in the Microsoft documentation

However, if you want a TimeSpan type of value format, you will have to convert the DateTime (or milliseconds) to a TimeSpan instead and it should format as you would expect automatically.  Otherwise, you can use a [custom TimeSpan format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings).

If you only have a milliseconds value, then you will have to convert that to a TimeSpan using `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(ms)`

A little more detail about what your data models look like would help provide more clarity.

Let me know if that helps or not.